# How to enter a list of codes in the text field, through "," and get the same number of separate objects Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

I am writing one project Ruby on Rails, and i'm stuck in one place.. I have a class Product, this class `has_many:` class Codes. Now, i enter the codes one at a time into the text box, and I get one object with one code.
I want to enter a list of codes in the text field, through "," and get the same number of separate objects.

I am getting this error -
TypeError in GiftCodesController#create
no implicit conversion of String into Integer

When I check with a debugger, I don't see any Integer

```
@code = Code.new(code_params)
        if @code.code.include? ","
            @array = @code.ode.split(",")
            @array.each do |n| 
              @code.code = @array[n]
              @code.save
            end
            flash[:success] = "Code´s added!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            if @code.save
                flash[:success] = "Code added!"
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                flash[:danger] = "Error!"
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` method returns the VALUE of each array element, not the index.

So this is wrong...

```
@array.each do |n| 
  @code.code = @array[n]
  @code.save
end
```

This would be correct...

So this is wrong...

```
@array.each do |n| 
  @code.code = n
  @code.save
end
```

But even that would be wrong, as you want to create a new code for each array element, so...

```
@array.each do |n| 
  code = @product.codes.build
  code.code = n
  code.save
end
```

There are some edge cases you'll also need to address, like how to edit existing codes for a product, but hopefully this will start you off.